# Removing occurrences of characters in a string

Tags: algorithms, strings

I am reading [this book, Programming Interviews Exposed by John Mongan et. al](http://amzn.com/0471383562) and in chapter 6 they are discussing removing all instances of characters in a src string using a removal string, e.g. `removeChars(string str, string remove)`.

They suggest to having a boolean lookup array with all values initially set to false, then loop through each character in `remove` setting the corresponding value in the lookup array to true. (note: this could also be a hash if the possible character set where huge like Unicode-16 or something like that or if `str` and remove are both relatively small... < 100 characters I suppose).  You then iterate through the `str` with a source and destination index, copying each character only if its corresponding value in the lookup array is false...

I understand their explanation, but I don't understand their code. They have

```
for(src = 0; src < len; ++src){
   flags[r[src]] == true;
}
```

which turns the flag value at the `remove` string indexed at src to true...

so if you start out with `PLEASE HELP` as your str and `LEA` as your remove you will be setting in your flag table at `0,1,2... t|t|t` but after that you will get an out of bounds exception because r doesn't have have anything greater than 2 in it. Even using their example you get an out of bounds exception. Is their code example unworkable?

#### Entire Function:

```
string removeChars( string str, string remove ){
   char[] s = str.toCharArray();
   char[] r = remove.toCharArray();
   bool[] flags = new bool[128]; // assumes ASCII!
   int len = s.Length;
   int src, dst;
   // Set flags for characters to be removed
   for( src = 0; src < len; ++src ){
      flags[r[src]] = true;
    }

   src = 0;
   dst = 0;
   // Now loop through all the characters,
   // copying only if they aren’t flagged
   while( src < len ){
       if( !flags[ (int)s[src] ] ){
       s[dst++] = s[src];
   }
   ++src;
   }
   return new string( s, 0, dst );
}
```

`r` comes from the remove string.  So in my example the remove string has only a size of 3 while my `str` string has a size of 11.  `len` is equal to the length of the `str` string, which would be 11.  How can I loop through the `r` string since it is only size 3?  I haven't compiled the code so I can loop through it, but just looking at it I know it won't work.  I am thinking they wanted to loop through the `r` string... in other words they got the length of the wrong string here.

Am I right? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: There's an error in the book's code.  The len in the first for loop should be the remove characters length, not the source characters length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a lot of code here to work with and it's unlikely everyone has a copy of this book, so this is a guess! It would help if you would post more code.

Using your `PLEASE HELP` & `LEA` example, I'd wager the `flags` array is a lookup table indexed by the ASCII value of a character, and at the end would look like:

```
flags['A'] -> true
flags['B'] -> false
...
flags['E'] -> true
...
flags['L'] -> true
... (everything else would be false)
```

Then when doing the removed copy the routine would see that

```
flags['P'] -> false, so copy it
flags['L'] -> true, so don't copy
flags['E'] -> true, so don't copy
etc
```

'P' is the ASCII value of character P.

Comment: +1, I guess you are correct. However, the algorithm (not your answer) looks like it has an issue. Say you have a string "Please help her there not here" and you want to remove the string "here", the flags array would set the flags for the letters "h","e","r" to don't copy and the string "her" as well as the string "here" would both be removed.

Comment: @EmmadKareem True, but the question seems to ask about Interview questions and so they may be expecting the interviewee to bring up your point for bonus marks.

Comment: This is very clever! You must be working for the book publisher:)

Comment: I just expanded my comments, what are your thoughts.

Comment: Oh yeah, emmad, think of the remove string as an array of characters that should not occur in the original string.  Removing her and here would be a correct result.

Comment: @DmainEvent I think you're right, it's a typo. They should use `r.length` instead of `len`

Comment: yep... just finished running the algorithm.  It works with that change.  BTW,  I didn't know an array indexed with a char would translate that char to the ascii index of that char... Very good stuff indeed.